# C System Programming with fork()

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

Okay what the heck am I doing wrong? I am doing this on Ubuntu and I want this to take the system command "ls" and a parameter such as "-a" and then have the child execute it and then the parent just print something out. I can't understand why I keep getting "Parent" returned twice. Any ideas?

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include  <sys/types.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void Cprocess(char *commands, char *scommands[]);
void Pprocess(void);

void main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

    char *sendcommand[] = {argv[1],argv[2],0};
    char *commands = argv[0];
    int pid;

    if((pid=fork()) ==-1)
    {
            perror("Error!!\n");
    }
    else if(pid==0)
            Cprocess(commands, sendcommand);
    else
    {
            wait(0);
            printf("Parent\n");
    }
}
void Cprocess(char *argv1, char *argv2[])
{
    execvp(argv1, argv2);
    exit(19);
}
```

That wasn't very nice of me here is the command I enter:

```
./filename ls -a
```

Here is my result:

```
filename1   filename2   filename3
Parent
Parent
```

Comment: You are telling your child to run `command` which is `argv[0]`, which is the current program.  Presumably, you meant to copy `argv[1]` rather than `argv[0]`?  Or you could do without the separate `command` and simply use `sendcommand[0]` as the first argument to `execvp()`.  I've not tracked why you don't get many copies of the child running the parent again, though.

Comment: BTW: main() should return int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Congratulations: your program pretty much works.  I think you've made things a bit more complicated than they need to be by interposing the `Cprocess()` function; without it, what's going on might be a bit clearer.  Allow me to rearrange your program a bit:

```
void main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    int pid = fork();

    if (pid ==-1) {
        perror("Error!!\n");
    } else if (pid==0) {
        char *sendcommand[] = { argv[1], argv[2], 0 };
        execvp(argv[0], sendcommand);
        exit(19);
    } else {
        wait(0);
        printf("Parent\n");
    }
}
```

That's functionally equivalent to your original `main()`, and I bet you'll see the problem in it right away.

Hint:

> Look carefully at the arguments to `execvp()`.

Hint 2:

> The first argument to `execvp()` designates the program to run.

Hint 3:

> Are you serious?  Put your brain to work, or at least your debugger.

Comment: Added your code exactly and changed: execvp(argv[0], sendcommand); to execvp(argv[1], sendcommand); and it worked. why did I get two responses?

P.S. like the hints!

Comment: The `argv[0]` received by your program among its arguments is, normally, the name of the program itself.  If you pass that as the first argument to `execvp()` then you're telling it to run another copy of the parent program.  Note also that the array passed as the second argument to `execvp()` is expected to follow the same convention -- the first element (at index 0) is expected to be the program name in some form; the actual arguments start at index 1.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response and explanation.